# Problem with running react-native android on mac Os

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native, gradle

i am new to react native running `yarn android` i get an error concerning gradle...

i will be greatfull if anyone can help me..

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Settings file '/Users/username/Desktop/personal projects/appname/android/settings.gradle'
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile settings file '/Users/username/Desktop/personal projects/appname/android/settings.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 61

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61`

Comment: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13629 According to this issue, Java 16 is not supported yet, can you try to downgrade your java/jdk version?

Comment: i have downgraded it i now get this error \

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/gift/Desktop/personal projects/geezyApp/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.`

Comment: You should set ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME env variables. https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is being caused because of one of the following reasons;

1. **Misconfigured Java Run-time**
2. **Misconfigured Android SDK**

I'd advise you to follow the guide at **[ReactNative.dev](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)**